# Find the minimum,maximum, infimum and supremum of sets?

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

If $X$ is the intersection of all the intervals $(1-\frac{1}{n^2},1+\frac{5}{n^3}]$ for $n=1$ to infinity, what is the minimum, maximum, supremum and infimum of $X$?

If $Y$ is the intersection of all the intervals $(1-\frac{1}{n^3},1+\frac{1}{n})$ for $n=1$ to infinity, what is the minimum, maximum, supremum and infimum of $Y$?

I have $X=(1,1]$  and $Y=(1,1)$  which I think are both empty? My guess is that there is no minimum or maximum for either $X$  or $Y$ . I don't know whether the infimums/supremums are $1$ or whether you say they are infinite or something. I'm not sure what to do with the empty sets.

Comment: Can you determine $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please take a moment to add some context to your question, such as what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.  You will find people on this site much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: @martini have $X=(1,1]$ and $Y=(1,1)$ which I think are both empty? My guess is that there is no minimum or maximum for either $X$ or $Y$. I don't know whether the infimums/supremums are 1 or whether you say they are infinite or something. I'm not sure what to do with the empty sets.

Comment: You can show that both $X$ and $Y$ contain the point $1$, but not any other point, this means that $X=Y=[1,1]=\{1\}$ Thus the maximum/minimum/supremum/infemum are all equal to 1.

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the definition of supremum and infimum. I advise you consult your notes/text.